# C# WInform ,Passing next value to the next form, HOW

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication

how will I pass data from database to the next Winform, like in php called session)

I wanted to show, a welcome message showing NICKNAME on the 2nd form, instead of USER ID, Please show me in most easiest way, Thanks

Below is my code for Loginpage:

```
try //***************TRY START****************
{
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from Account where User_ID='" + userID.Text + "' and Pass='" + Password.Text + "';", con);
    OleDbDataReader myReader;
    con.Open();
    myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    int count = 0;
    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        count = count + 1;
    }

    if (count == 1)
    {
        string s = userID.Text;
        MessageBox.Show(s);
        this.Hide();
        AdminPanel us = new AdminPanel();
        us.Show();
    }
    else  
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid ");
    }
    con.Close();
} // ******END TRY********
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Please format your code better.  It is indented half-way off the page.

Answer (score 2):

you can create constructor in Form2 to accept nickname

```
public Form2(string nickname)
{
  InitializeComponent(); 
  label1.Text=nickname;
}
```

in your 1st page, read the nickname from `myReader` and pass it to Form2

```
con.Open();
OleDbDataReader myReader= cmd.ExecuteReader();
if(myReader.Read())
{
       string nickname= myReader["Nickname"].ToString(); // give correct column name as your database
       Form2 frm=new Form2(nickname); 
       frm.Show();
}else  
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid ");
}
```

Comment: it says nickname doesnt exist on the first form

Comment: Hello again damith, is it possible to pass it on a 3rd form? im wondering coz it gives me form, but no name at all. thanks

Comment: Just make the constructor for Form3 accept a string nickname aswell, then just pass along the nickname stored in "string nickname" in Form2.